# raising an exception if a parameter is a string

Tags: python

I have seen other posts/videos in order to figure out how to solve this issue I am having but with no success. I am trying to raise an exception if the third parameter(p) is a string datatype but all my attempts in order to achieve this have not been successful and was looking for some help on what I am doing wrong.

```py
class Friends(Ben):
    def __init__(self, frank, greg, p):
        Ben.__init__(self, frank, greg)
        self.p = p

        try:
            if p == str:
                raise TypeError("This is a string!")
        except:
            print("This not a string")
```

Comment: Read docs about `isinstance()` and `type()`.

Comment: ok @MichaelButscher

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The current code won't run at all. Please show runnable code, the results you get from it, and explain how that differs from expected.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of oddities in your piece of code; however, to address the issue of raising an Exception, you use `raise` to do that, as other answers indicate.

The `try`/`except` syntax is used to catch and handle exceptions when they occur. As an example, here is a reworked, standalone version of your code snippet that illustrates this.

```
class Friends:
    def __init__(self, frank, greg, p):
        if isinstance(p, str):
            raise TypeError(p, "This is a string!")
        self.p = p

try:
    friends = Friends('Frank', 'Greg', 'dubious_string')
except TypeError as e:
    print("Hey, I caught the error!")
    # print the exception
    print(e)
    # raise the exception again
    raise e
```

Output:

```
Hey, I caught the error!
('dubious_string', 'This is a string!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise e
  File "tmp.py", line 10, in <module>
    friends = Friends('Frank', 'Greg', 'dubious_string')
  File "tmp.py", line 5, in __init__
    raise TypeError(p, "This is a string!")
TypeError: ('dubious_string', 'This is a string!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the class, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
#p = 10
p = "some string"
if type(p) == str:
    raise Exception("This is a string")
```

Comment: This will not cover subclasses of string, but it will work for most day to day scenarios.

Comment: True, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Ben:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Friends(Ben):
    def __init__(self,frank,greg,p):

        if isinstance(p, str):
            raise TypeError('Why are you giving me strings!')

        Ben.__init__(frank,greg)
        self.p = p

group = Friends('frank', 'greg', 'evil_string')
```

Output:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StackOverflow\Desktop\temp.py", line 15, in <module>
    group = Friends('frank', 'greg', 'evil_string')
  File "C:\Users\StackOverflow\Desktop\temp.py", line 10, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Why are you giving me strings!')
TypeError: Why are you giving me strings!
```